# playback speed faster than normal speed on linux mint's default video player

Tags: linux, video, linux-mint

How do I watch videos with a playback speed faster than normal speed on Linux mint's default video player? I don't see an option to do so. For example x2 speed. Is that possible or do I have to download a third-party video player? I am using Linux Mint Uno.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not directly accessible from the menu as it is in the older Totem video player, but you can change the playback speed from the keyboard:

<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> decreases and increases playback speed by 10% respectively

<kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd> decreases and increases playback speed by x2, respectively

<kbd>backspace</kbd> resets playback to normal speed.

Ref: https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#keyboard-control